# Several functional analysis questions

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I've an exam tomorrow, and was regarding the last year's one. TRUE OR FALSE and why whoever wants to try, no need.

1. If E is a normed space with all its separable subspaces being reflexive, then E itself is reflexive.
2. Every reflexive subspace of $l¹$ is finite dimensional.
3. If E is a normed space and $T$ a compact operator such that $T²=T$, then T has finite dimensional range.

Thanks.

Comment: for 2. I thought the following. If $A \in l¹$ then $l\infty \in E'$ which is reflexive, contradiction. So $l¹$ doesn't have reflexive subspaces. So TRUE. Is it OK?

Comment: 3 is TRUE because $\ker(I-T)$ is finite dimensional and $T(E)$ is contained in it because $T²=T$ implies $(T-I)T=0$

Comment: in my first comment I meant contained instead of belongs

Comment: my first comment must be wrong, since that same argument would prove that any non-reflexive space has all its subspaces nonreflexive. but we know that any separabale space (say $l^2$) can be isomorphically embedded into $l^{\infty}$ right?

Comment: For 1, one can use the Eberlein-Smulian theorem, which implies that $E$ is reflexive if and only if every bounded sequence in $E$ has a weakly convergent subsequence. So reflexivity is determined by sequences, and hence by the separable subspaces of $E$ (looking at the closed linear span of a given sequence). For 2, the answer is also TRUE: any infinite-dimensional subspace of $\ell_1$ contains a subspace isomorphic to $\ell_1$, and hence cannot be reflexive.